# Collecting Methods, Attributes and name of Class in MyClass.java

Tags: java, reflection

Well, I need to receive a Class from User, like: MyClass.java. My program needs to read all class and identify the: methods, class attributes and class name.

SO i think in some possibilites:

1 - Use Reflection to do this task more fast, but the problem with reflection is that i'll need a MyClass.class (bytecode) and user will send a ".java", so reflection is discarted.

2 - Create a super algorithm with a lot of regex expressions to do this task. This solutions can work but this regex will be very complex.

3 - Create some parser based on BNF Grammar to do this task. I think this is more easy solution, but i don't know how start in this point.

Well, i hope that you can help me to find a better solution.

Comment: You can always compile the `.java` file when you receive it, in code or with a `ProcessBuilder` for `javac`. Then load its class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i don't wanna "compile" my .java, i just wanna identify the methods, attributes and the name of class in run-time. Like i "reflection" but in a ".java" file.

Comment: Will the "MyClass.java" include references to things you don't have access to?  EG: Will MyClass.java use a `import ClassFromAnotherJar` and you don't have the jar on your classpath?

Comment: MyClass.java can include references to another class, but i'll have only the "MyClass.java", i must ignore this references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to give a look to Java parser which is open source and ,among other things, doing what you are looking for:

https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser

Comment: Java parser just works for java 1.5, and most of people use java 6, including me.

Comment: You need to get just the idea. I understod you wan to implement the stuff. you cannot expect a solution here on such a topic. Another idea: https://github.com/antlrjavaparser/antlr-java-parser. In general check antlr.

Comment: I liked java parser, but my big doubt is: can i use java parse 1.5 with java 1.6 without problems ? Or this is impossible ?

Comment: Ofc you will have problems. I think that if you need only attribute methods and class name will be ok. Not for more sophisticated thing. You should check in the site I linked in the answer and also be perfectly aware of your requirements and constraints

Comment: thanks @blackbird014, i got the methods and attributes with Java Parser, nothing more sophisticated. This is all that i need: Name of Methods, name of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a code analyzer such as [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/). It includes parsers for different versions of java.

Comment: I don't know PMD, but i'll study it and answer here if this works. Thanks @aditsu